# unable to access ssh at port 4422 on AWS

Tags: ubuntu, aws, window, rdp

I have access to a cluster (paramshivay.iitbhu.ac.in) via port 4422

I can easily connect it by regular internet connection
but whenever I try it to connect via AWS (either on ubuntu ssh instance or window RDP), it went time out.

I need this cluster to access on AWS to transfer huge amount of files so that I can backup them on google-drive (approx 3TB data)
I have tried editing the security group to open all networks, still no luck.
[image]

the general command I use to connect is: `ssh -X -p4422 user@paramshivay.iitbhu.ac.in`

Comment: What do you mean by "easily connect it by regular internet connection"? Could you try to add -v (verbose) to your command and paste the log?

Comment: regular internet means my Mobile ISP internet and accessing over my personal laptop or mobile, I think allowing port on AWS is a bit tricky whether on the mobile network it's already open for all.
the -v on amazon (ubuntu) instance print this: [patebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/2KsBFcz42w/) @Hugh

Comment: Could you please try to do `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp; sudo ufw reload` on your ubuntu instance (ip-172-31-61-135) and paste again with -v?

Comment: yes. please find it here [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DDB6N3W4fV/)

Comment: ufw is not enabled so it may be a problem on you AWS network group outbound configuration. Could you please sent a screenshot of the outboud configuration for (ip-172-31-61-135). It's the same page than the screenshot you sent but you have to click on the outbound tab

Comment: yeah sure, here it is: https://pasteboard.co/JnAkWBL.png

Comment: Sorry I'm out of option then. My guess is your port 22 is not open for outbound connection on ip-172-31-61-135 but I'm not sure why